# Convert JAL to VBScript

Tags: vbscript

24x7 from SoftTree Technologies can use both JAL and VBScript for scripting.  Does anyone know if there is a converter to change JAL into VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be such a thing.  You can convert JAL to Javascript, but not JAL to VBScript.